# Correct Kerberos principal type for a hostbased service

Tags: java, kerberos, principal, gssapi, jgss

There are [several types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/security/auth/kerberos/KerberosPrincipal.html) of Kerberos principals. A regular user princpal like `michael-o@COMPANY.COM` would be `KRB_NT_PRINCIPAL`. But what about a service like `HTTP/host.company.com@COMPANY.COM`? There are a few possible types like `KRB_NT_SRV_{INST|HST|XHST}`. What is the correct one?

From my understanding `INST` is for TGTs only.
I would assume that the correct answer should be `HST`. I wasn't able to find a clue in Oracle's JDK source code but these two contradicting points: [1](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/security/krb5/Credentials.java#106) vs. [2](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/security/krb5/KrbCred.java#80).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RFC 4120](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4120) section 7.5.8 defines the nametypes.  In practice most everything uses KRB_NT_SRV_HST.  I have never seen KRB_NT_SRV_XHST except in the RFCs and in test code.  In general KRB_NT_SRV_INST is used when the second component is not a hostname.  Examples include TGTs, or other replicated services where it doesn't matter which host you get.  However, name types don't matter that much. Section 6.2 describes this:

> As was the case for realm names, conventions are needed to ensure
> that all agree on what information is implied by a principal name.
> The name-type field that is part of the principal name indicates the
> kind of information implied by the name.  The name-type SHOULD be
> treated only as a hint to interpreting the meaning of a name.  It is
> not significant when checking for equivalence.  Principal names that
> differ only in the name-type identify the same principal.  The name
> type does not partition the name space.  Ignoring the name type, no
> two names can be the same (i.e., at least one of the components, or
> the realm, MUST be different).  The following name types are defined:
> Modern Kerberos implementations do treat KRB_NT_SRV_HST a bit specially.  In particular, they are more likely to generate cross-realm referrals based on the hostname in the second component of such a principal.  So if the first component identifies a service and the second identifies a host name, SRV_HST is best.

Answer (score 0):

RFC 1510 is a better reference for this. See http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1510.txt
section 7.2.1
"The principal identifier for a server on a host will generally be
   composed of two parts: (1) the realm of the KDC with which the server
   is registered, and (2) a two-component name of type NT-SRV-HST if the
   host name is an Internet domain name or a multi-component name of
   type NT-SRV-XHST if the name of the host is of a form such as X.500
   that allows slash (/) separators.  The first component of the two- or
   multi-component name will identify the service and the latter
   components will identify the host.  Where the name of the host is not
   case sensitive (for example, with Internet domain names) the name of
   the host must be lower case.  For services such as telnet and the
   Berkeley R commands which run with system privileges, the first
   component will be the string "host" instead of a service specific
   identifier.
"